# How to Convert an array into Object using javascript without using Object.assign

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had an array

```
[{0:{title:"test1"}},{1:{message1:"message1"}},{2:{message2:"message2"}}]
```

I want to get an Object in below format

```
{title:"test1",message1:"message1",message2:"message2"}
```

I am trying with below code but no luck

```
var rv = {};
for (var i = 0; i < messageArray.length; ++i)
if (messageArray[i] !== undefined) rv[i] = messageArray[i];`
```

It results me

```
{0: {title:"test1"}, 1: {message1:"message1"},2: {message2:"message2"}}
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe that what you've shown is actually the content of your array. Are you sure? It's very, very strange.

Comment: Yes thats my array :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your array flat

```
const rv = [];
for (var i = 0; i < messageArray.length; ++i) {
   if (messageArray[i] !== undefined)
      rv.push(messageArray[i]);
}
```

Then can use `Array.reduce`, it should look like

```
rv.reduce((result, element) => {
   Object.keys(element).forEach((key) => {
      result[key] = element[key];
   });
   return result;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` to summarize the data and `Object.assign()` to merge new properties into an object.

```js
let arr = [{0:{title:"test1"}},{1:{message1:"message1"}},{2:{message2:"message2"}}];

let result = arr.reduce((c, v, i) => Object.assign(c, v[i]),{});

console.log(result);
```

If the key on your objects are not on sequence, you can use `Object.values()` to get the values.

```js
let arr = [{0:{title:"test1"}},{1:{message1:"message1"}},{2:{message2:"message2"}}];

let result = arr.reduce((c, v, i) => Object.assign(c, Object.values(v)[0]), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` and `.reduce()`:

```js
let data = [
  {0:{title:"test1"}},
  {1:{message1:"message1"}},
  {2:{message2:"message2"}}
];

let result = data.map((c, i) => c[i])
                 .reduce((a, c) => Object.assign(a, c), {});

console.log(result);
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the items by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). Then get the internal values via [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), and merge them again by spreading into `Object.assign()`:

```js
const data = [{0:{title:"test1"}},{1:{message1:"message1"}},{2:{message2:"message2"}}];

const result = Object.assign(...Object.values(Object.assign({}, ...data)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each property, and use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to extend the current object with each property.

```js
var object = {};
var input = [{0:{title:"test1"}},{1:{message1:"message1"}},{2:{message2:"message2"}}];

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    object = Object.assign(input[i][i], object);
}

console.log(object);

/*
{
  "message2": "message2",
  "message1": "message1",
  "title": "test1"
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should give desired results **without Object.assign** :

```
  //Using map() and reduce()
  var arr = [{0:{title:"test1"}},{1:{message1:"message1"}},{2:{message2:"message2"}}];

  var result = arr.map(function(item,i){
    return item[i];
  })
  .reduce(function(acc,item){
    return {...acc,...item}
  },{})

  console.log(result); // {title: "test1", message1: "message1", message2: "message2"}
```

Hope this helps!